# transitionend Listener only firing for parent

Tags: javascript, transition

I have a parent and child div.  Both have event listeners for `transitionend`, and both have animations that are triggered at the same time. The problem is the `transitionend` listener only fires for the parent, and never for the child. The event is meant to remove/add classes to the divs that will reset them to their original state.

I made a JS Fiddle that shows a simplified version of the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/78vxes6o/2/

```
var createEventListener = function(element, removeClass, addCLass) {
  return element.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove("animating", removeClass);
    event.target.classList.add(addCLass);
    return true;
  }, false);
}
```

CSS:

```
.animating {
  transition: transform 1s;
  &.main {
    background: purple;
  }
  &.second {
    background: orange;
  }
}
```

In the fiddle, after the transition ends, the lower div stays orange, instead of reverting to red. That means that the "animating" class didn't get removed, and the event didn't get fired.

Why not?

Comment: Please post code here. JSFiddle can go down or decide to delete all fiddles

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

OP's test demo over complicated. The following demo...

- Has a `#parent` and `#child` `<section>`
- Both subjects have identical animation properties `transform:rotate(1800deg)` and `transition:transform 1s`.
- The animation is triggered by `:hover`
- A simple jQuery function will alert on each `transition:transform` event fired. The alert will identify the `e.target` as "parent" or "child".

There should only be 2 alerts on one *complete hover*, meaning the mouse must pass over both `<section>`s in order to see a successful test. If merely hovering over the `#parent` and expecting `#child` to trigger `transitionEnd` simply because it's spinning along with it's parent, is faulty logic. In order to trigger an event there usually needs to be real interaction between element and user action (at least in this case).

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    section {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
      transition: transform 1s;
    }
    section:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(1800deg);
      transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
    #parent {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      outline: 5px dashed blue;
      margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    }
    #child {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      outline: 2px solid red;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 12.5%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <section id='parent'>PARENT
    <section id='child'>CHILD</section>
  </section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('section').each(function(i) {
      $(this).on('webkitTransitionEnd transitionEnd', function(e) {
        var self = this;
        if (e.target == this) {
          var tgt = e.target.id;
          alert(tgt + " has reached transition end");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Set the transition to `all`

[<kbd>**FIDDLE**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/grr00d4d/)

#### Changes

```
.animating {
  transition: all 1s; /* changed */
}
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var second = document.getElementById("second");

 createEventListener(main, "expanded", "open");
  createEventListener(second, "open", "collapsed");
  
  second.classList.add("animating", "open");
  main.classList.add("animating", "expanded");

  second.classList.remove("collapsed");
  main.classList.remove("open");
}, true);

var createEventListener = function(element, removeClass, addCLass) {
  return element.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove("animating", removeClass);
    event.currentTarget.classList.add(addCLass);
    return true;
  }, true);
}
```

```css
.group {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.main.open {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.second.open {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.expanded {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.collapsed {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.animating {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.animating.main {
  background: purple;
}
.animating.second {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Run</button>

<div class="group">
  <div class="main open" id="main">
    <div class="second collapsed" id="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if I want to animate multiple properties.  In my case, I've only added the colors to the `.animate` class to illustrate that the classes are not removed.  If you remove the colors from your example and then inspect the child element after running it, it will still have the `animating` and `open` classes instead of having the `collapsed` class.

Comment: I forgot to mention I had changed `event.target` to `event.currentTarget`, I don't remember what I was trying to do (very late in my timezone). You should narrow down your test case down to one class and one transform if you are actually testing a class called collapse and the event 'transitionend', wouldn't it be far easier to do so without everything else in the way?